# Copy data from multiple workbooks using vba when each row of destination represents a workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I’m trying to go down a schedule and pull information from the corresponding workbooks, each row would represent a pre-defined workbook.  I would prefer this to be within VBA, since I don’t like the external workbook links (i.e., indirect, index, etc), not too mention this will be 500+ lines down.

I have the file path designated in another worksheet, I have a hyperlink to each file in column B of this sheet.  When I run the macro it’s currently getting hung up on me setting Name.  I’m not sure what to try next.  I have posted the code I have so far.  Please help!

```
Option Explicit
Sub Pull_Data()

    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim msh As Worksheet 
    Dim dsh As Worksheet 
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim MyFile As String
    Dim Name As String

    Set msh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master")
    Dim MyPath As String: MyPath = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Inputs").Range("M3")
    MyFile = Dir(MyPath & "/*.xlsx")

    For i = 7 To msh.Range("B" & Application.Rows.count).End(xlUp).row

    Do While MyFile <> "" And MyFile <> ThisWorkbook.Name
    If MyFile = msh.Range("B" & i).Value & ".xlsx" Then
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & "/" & MyFile)
        Set dsh = wb.Worksheets("Blank")
                msh.Range("D" & i).Value = dsh.Range("M80").Value
                msh.Range("E" & i).Value = dsh.Range("N80").Value
                msh.Range("F" & i).Value = dsh.Range("O80").Value
                msh.Range("G" & i).Value = dsh.Range("P80").Value
                msh.Range("H" & i).Value = dsh.Range("Q80").Value
                msh.Range("I" & i).Value = dsh.Range("R80").Value
                msh.Range("J" & i).Value = dsh.Range("S80").Value
                msh.Range("K" & i).Value = dsh.Range("T80").Value
            wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
        End If
            MyFile = Dir()
        Loop
   Next i
   MsgBox "Done"
    With Application
         .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
         .DisplayAlerts = True
         .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Remove the `Set` when you write the filename to `Name`. `Set` is only needed when you assign an object (object reference), eg. a Worksheet, but not for simple variables like numbers or strings. One remark: Unless you are on a Mac, you have to use `\ ` (backslash) and not `/` (slash) in the `Dir`-command

Comment: FunThomas Thanks for the quick response.  When I remove the Set Name.  The macro does not work as intended, it actually appears to pull in no information at all.  How do I get the macro to pull the correct file information to each row?

Comment: Sorry, impossible to tell, I don't have your data. Have you tried to debug your code step by step (use F8) to see where it fails?  Does the `Dir` find the files? Are the files opened correctly? Is the sheet variable `dsh` set to anything? What is the content of cells like `dsh.Range("M80").Value`?

Comment: I have changed the code above.   When I removed the Set Name, I then had to replace Name with what I was setting it to.  It then brings over the 1st row information from the 1st file correctly.  Then it doesn't bring over the rest of the rows information.  So it's a problem with moving to the next row.  Going step-by-step through the macro, it never gets a 2nd file, for some reason the Next i, doesn't start it back over again.

Comment: You messed up your logic with the `Dir` vs the `For`-Loop. Basically, you need the `Dir` only to check if the file you want to read exists, so put a statement like `If Dir(MyPath & "\" & name) <> "" Then... *Inside* the `For` loop. No need to loop over all Excel Files in that folder if you know already the name of the file.

Comment: That concept fixed it.  I did have to do some other tweaks, but it now works.  I will post the final code.

Answer (score 0):

After incorporating the comments from FunThomas, here is the final code that works:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Pull_Data()

    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim msh As Worksheet 
    Dim dsh As Worksheet 
    Dim i As Integer

    Set msh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master")
    Dim MyPath As String: MyPath = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Inputs").Range("M3")

    For i = 7 To msh.Range("B" & Application.Rows.count).End(xlUp).row

    If Dir(MyPath & "\" & msh.Range("B" & i).Value & ".xlsx") <> "" Then
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & "\" & msh.Range("B" & i).Value & ".xlsx")
        Set dsh = wb.Worksheets("Blank")
                msh.Range("D" & i).Value = dsh.Range("M80").Value
                msh.Range("E" & i).Value = dsh.Range("N80").Value
                msh.Range("F" & i).Value = dsh.Range("O80").Value
                msh.Range("G" & i).Value = dsh.Range("P80").Value
                msh.Range("H" & i).Value = dsh.Range("Q80").Value
                msh.Range("I" & i).Value = dsh.Range("R80").Value
                msh.Range("J" & i).Value = dsh.Range("S80").Value
                msh.Range("K" & i).Value = dsh.Range("T80").Value
            wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
        End If

   Next i
   MsgBox "Done"
    With Application
         .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
         .DisplayAlerts = True
         .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```